# What is the recommended way to write mathematical notations in inline text?

Tags: math-mode, inline

I want to write a math notation in inline text, example notations: `$d$, $i$, $i'$, $i.low$, $i'.high$, $i'high \leq i.low$`, example in sentences: `

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
The interval trichotomy for closed intervals $i$ and $i'$... The intervals do not overlap, and $i'.high \le i.low$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But in [Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FH8N996) book, I observe that all the math notations are written in italic, I believe `\textit(i.high)` generates it, rathar than using `$...$`, example:

[image]

When I try `\textit($i.low$)` it does not makes it italic or if I do `$i.\mathrm{high$}` , `high` string does not much differ from the inline text.

Would it be fine if I use `$i.low$` or should I find a way to make it italic. What is the recommended or common way to write mathematical notations in inline text?

Comment: never use math italic for words so `$i.\mathit{high}$` not `$i.high$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the fast response. Is math italic stands for `$\textit{high}$`? As I understand `$i.\mathit{high}$` is correct way to do it; and for single words I can just do $i$ but not `$mathit{i}$`

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage{eulervm}` or something to the same effect. If you’re not able to, please add a minimal example showing the obtained output.

Comment: no by math italic I mean the default math font `$high$` which is designed to separate the letters so they denote a product of one-letter variables, not a word. Compare `$diff$` and `$\mathit{diff}$`

Comment: I usually never use the dollar for inline math but instead backslash followed by round parenthesis...

Comment: @P.Oliva I will switch using `\( ... \)`thanks for the heads up

Comment: @egreg Ah your are right I have `\usepackage{eulervm}` and its not on the journal's template. Removing `\usepackage{eulervm}` makes all italic, it but now its hard to get used to the format without `\usepackage{eulervm}` :-) for example `$B_{H_{\!d_{\!\left|\!D\!\right|$` was readible with `\usepackage{eulervm}`; but without it it looks way different . I have added minimal example for the clearity of the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle when I removed`\usepackage{eulervm}`: $i.\mathit{high}$ and $i.high$ have the same output, seems like by default `$i.\mathit{high}$` is handled

Comment: @alper they are not at all the same, $high$ uses a different, wider font [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkled.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks I see the difference now :-)  same would apply for the sub-scripts or super-script right? like: $i_\mathit{high}$ or $i^\mathit{high}$

Comment: yes but `i^{\mathit{high}}` always brace sub and superscripts. The rules of when you can leave out the braces are "interesting"